# Как убрать адресную строку в TWA приложении?

Tags: android

Не понимаю как убрать адресную строку в TWA в приложении, нашел в интернете какой-то гайд по первой ссылке (он там единственный), но автор не совсем ясно выразился(Скорее я просто тупой, и ничего не понял). Но из его гайда я понял, что нужно подтвердить владение доменов для приложения TWA.

- Так ли это ?
- И как это сделать ?

[image: Как убрать адресную строку в TWA приложении?]